# Turning on/off network settings on Android

Tags: java, android, networking

Is there a (simple) possibility for turning the mobile network on/off with Java code?
If so, for mobile service too?
'Cause I'd like to make an app which turns the network on and service off (or the opposite).

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2):

The wireless network you can turn on by the following code:

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Thanks, but if I try my app crashes while executing the code above.

Comment: could you post the exception? maybe you havent add

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>

to the manifest. i should have mentioned that. sorry.

Comment: Does this only work for Wifi or also for the mobile network (i.e. 3G) ? Since the original question was about the mobile network.

Answer (score 0):

You need permissions to do that. I think CHANGE_WIFI_STATE is the right one.

Comment: I'm quite a beginner, how do i put this?

Comment: Ah, found out myself, just had to add this into the AndroidManifest.xml
Thanks, guys!